# How can I find my exact percentile in a tag in developer story?

Tags: discussion, tags, developer-story

Where can I find the query to find my exact percentile of a tag like in the developer story?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could write a query using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer(SEDE), but you don't have to in this case as [Tim Stone's already done it for you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much consistency though; query shows I am it top 1% and 3% for `keras` and `scikit-learn` respectively, but in my dev story they show up as 5% and 10% respectively...

Comment: might be that they changed the way the % is calculated since Tim programmed it.

Comment: This isn't really the same as how it works for developer story.  Developer story doesn't require that you know the tags in advance that you might rank high for.  Developer story actually precomputes which tags you rank high for and suggest them for displaying.

Comment: The dev story tags were calculated across users **with a dev story**, not across all users. Since the SEDE never tracked what users have a dev story, the number could never be calculated correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternate SEDE query that computes the percentile for **all** of your (eligible) tags:

[data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given-user-in-all-of-his-eligible-tags?UserId=1475228)

<sub>(Be patient, it can take a couple minutes to run.)</sub>

Comment: What are the used criteria to consider a tag as eligible? For example, I have some answers/score on the `istio` tag, but it's not returned by the SEDE query. Another example: The top user of the `istio` tag does not have the `This user is part of the top X%`  in his Developer Story.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello, question votes don't count for tag score.  All of your `istio` rep, for example, is for questions you asked, so it doesn't count for tag score purposes.

Comment: This would be a good answer except that the query times out and pukes and error instead of providing the results. (sigh)

Answer (score 2):

I created the project [stackoverflow-readme-profile](https://stackoverflow-readme-profile.vercel.app/) ([github](https://github.com/johannchopin/stackoverflow-readme-profile)) that include a "tags league computation" amoung all user having at least a reputation of `3` for a given tag. This project enable you to share a dynamic badge like the following:

[image: user:8583669's ranking for svelte]

An "official" url is also provided to explain a bit more what this score means: https://stackoverflow-readme-profile.vercel.app/tags-league/svelte/users/8583669.

The computation is done thanks to [this](https://github.com/johannchopin/stackoverflow-readme-profile/blob/main/src/tags-league/SedeQueries/count_users_by_score_of_a_specific_tag.sql) SEDE query that count the amount of users by score for a given tag.