# Is there a minimum number of questions before tag top percentage badges appear on the developer story?

Tags: support, tags, developer-story

Is there a minimum number of questions before a tag might appear on the Developer Story?

Specifically I have been answering questions in the [[Pester]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pester/topusers) tag and am now the third all-time top answerer, but there have only ever been 63 questions :).

Also is there any way for me to calculate what my percentile is within a specific Tag? I think when this question was asked previously it redirected to a question about Tag Score (which I know it relates to), but I'm interested in understanding tag percentage calculation as well as what triggers tags to be displayed on your Developer Story.

Comment: second part is answered here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341280/how-can-i-find-my-exact-percentile-in-a-tag-in-developer-story/341282#341282

Comment: Thanks, although the query it links to doesn't seem to work any more, which isn't super surprising as it was written in 2011.

Comment: The query works when I run it.

Comment: You're right it works for me now. Maybe it was because I wasn't lowercasing the tag name earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my personal findings that you need to have `minimum total score 20` and also this tag should be "popular".

Percentage badge will not appear for unpopular tags. I am not sure about exact digit, but the `total number of user's questions` for this tag should be more than 1000. For now, tag [pester] has only 72 questions

And then you can use this query to know precise percent https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag