# Developer Story Tab - Top x% formula (updated?)

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers, developer-story

Currently, [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/10961238) shows *Top x%* for four tags as below.

[image]

I have found similar questions about how it is calculated.

[Is there a minimum number of questions before tag top percentage badges appear on the developer story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354782/is-there-a-minimum-number-of-questions-before-tag-top-percentage-badges-appear-o) states that

> You need a minimum total score 20 for popular tags which have more
>   than 1000 questions

[How can I find my exact percentile in a tag in developer story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341280/how-can-i-find-my-exact-percentile-in-a-tag-in-developer-story?noredirect=1&lq=1) refers to a SEDE query written in *April 2018* which results as follow

[image: query result]

As per query and above answer, *Top x%* should be as follow

[spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-security) *top 5%* instead of *top 10%* 
[jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa) should be there with *top 10%* 
[hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate) should be there with *top 10%* 
[spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) should be there with *top 10%*

It seems that stack-overflow has *updated the formula for top x%*. May I know how does it is calculated? *(I know that there are already asked question about the same but answers seems outdated for 2020)*

<sup>[spring-boot-actuator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot-actuator) and [spring-data-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) will not qualify because of less than 20 score</sup>