# How can I know how much score I need to get to a tag's top X%?

Tags: support, tags, developer-story

How can I know how much score I need to get to a tag's top X%?

e.g.

If I want to be top 1% in [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), what is the minimum score to have on that tag?

Comment: You’d have to run a SEDE query.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341280/how-can-i-find-my-exact-percentile-in-a-tag-in-developer-story

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried it and it's weird because some tags I'm in top X% but don't appear in my developer story. (Yes, I went there to edit the top tags, but only appear the ones that already was there)