# Where can I view my top tag percentages once the developer story is gone?

Tags: support, developer-story

The developer story has been [sunset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story). One nice feature of the developer story is that it makes it easy to see which tags I am ranking well in, and what percentage I have there.

> This user is part of the top 10% Stack Overflow answerers in this technology

This is useful for impressing people, in addition to just being interesting to see. Once the developer story site is fully gone in April 2022, where can I look that kind of information up easily?

---

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366601/2550406) points to a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given-user-in-all-of-his-eligible-tags?UserId=1475228) that computes the percentile for **all** of a user's tags. However, this times out for me.
[This other SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) does return a percentage given a tag and user-id, but needs to be run for every potentially relevant tag seperately.
Is there a place e.g. in the user profile where I can view this, that I simply have not found yet?

Comment: You can go to the tag's 'top users' page to see the top 20 users in asking and answering, both all-time and in the last 30 days. For anything other than that, you'll need to run a query against SEDE.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1696518/percentiles-in-tags-for-user) that calculates your percentile for all your tags.

Depending on the number of all answers in a tag, the query may take longer. For me it is just before the timeout.

Comment: The query never ended for me :(  https://gist.github.com/assets/3322836/b42176da-6315-461c-8045-17bccf92fd42