# Will the top % remain or will it also go with Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story, top-tag

As [Developer Story will be leaving Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story), will the top % showing like top 1%, top5% come back to profile or it will also go away?

Comment: [Where can I view my top tag percentages once the developer story is gone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415521/1426539)

Comment: [Request for some features to remain after sunsetting developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416017/1426539)

Comment: I guess either would work as a dupe target.

Comment: Sadly, neither have an answer...

Comment: This was also mentioned in this answer to the original announcement: [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415392/1426539)

Comment: @Cerbrus That's not an issue on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about these blocks:

[image]

Seeing as they're part of the actual page that's gonna be removed, they're, well, gone.

If you want that statistic elsewhere, I'd suggest you submit a feature request with an idea of where to add them.